# ElasticSearch duplicate results with paging

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using elasticsearch with pyes.  I'm getting duplicates in my last page of results.  Here's my query:

```
"query": {
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "and": [
                    {
                        "match_all": {

                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "minimum_number_should_match": 1,
                    "should": [
                        {
                            "text": {
                                "name.keyword_name": {
                                    "operator": "and",
                                    "query": "kentucky",
                                    "type": "boolean",
                                    "fuzziness": 0.8
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "text": {
                                "address": {
                                    "operator": "and",
                                    "query": "kentucky",
                                    "type": "boolean"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "text": {
                                "neighborhoods.name": {
                                    "operator": "and",
                                    "query": "kentucky",
                                    "type": "boolean",
                                    "fuzziness": 0.8
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "text": {
                                "categories.name": {
                                    "operator": "and",
                                    "query": "kentucky",
                                    "type": "boolean",
                                    "fuzziness": 0.8
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "facets": {
        "neighborhoods.id": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "neighborhoods.id",
                "size": 10
            }
        },
        "categories.id": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "categories.id",
                "size": 10
            }
        }
    },
    "size": 15,
    "from": 15,
    "fields": [
        "id",
        "categories.id",
        "name",
        "address",
        "city",
        "state",
        "zipcode",
        "location",
        "_id",
        "pos_review_count",
        "neg_review_count",
        "wishlist_count",
        "recommender_count",
        "checkin_count"
    ]
},
```

In this query, I have

```
    "size": 15,
    "from": 15,
```

and also for this particular query the total_count of objects returned is 24.  With a "from" at 15 and a total_count of 24, I'd like to be getting 9 results back here.  But instead, because I set "size" to 15, I get 15 results entries.  Since there are only 9 unique results left, 6 documents are being displayed twice. Any idea on how to make this give me 9 results rather than 15 with duplicates?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You might want to try search_type=scan and using the scroll api.

Comment: What version of ES are you using?  There was a bug in 0.90 that has been fixed.  You say "total_count" but that doesn't exist. Are you looking at the facet count or the hits total?  ie more info required

Comment: See https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/3078 for the bug

Answer (score 9):

If you have the data on multiple shards, it may return multiple times, I don't know why. Sorry, that is not very specific because I don't know why it happens.

Try using a preference: http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/search-request-preference.html

We use a preference custom string, and it fixed our duplicate data issue.

What is your replication setting? Is it possible the data is on multiple shards? What version are you using?

Unfortunately with pyes, you can't specify a preference on the multi search call. Try specifying a preference as a query parameter in the search call.

search(index=..., ....., preference=)

Answer (score 6):

The issue is that you're sorting by a field (or by default by the _score) which has duplicate values across docs. My understanding is that different shards may sort duplicate field values in different orders.

Therefore when you get a different shard for each request, you may get different sort orders, and therefore, you may get the same doc sorted onto two diff't pages (depending on which shard you asked).

As TheJeff mentioned above, the fix is to specify _search?preference=my-paging-key to ensure a consistent shard used for each of the page requests

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to share my experience here related to the same, I was also getting repeating results in different pages while using from/size paging parameters with the search query because of multiple shards.

I tried a few things documented here regarding [preferences in ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-preference.html#search-request-preference), and executing the query on primary shards have resolved the issue for me.

> "preference": "_primary_first"

If you are using python library, you can consider this reference:

https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.search

Answer (score 0):

Use of _primary and _primary_first is being deprecated as of 2023. Kindly adjust answers please